# opencv cant access analog camera

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

I have a analog camera whose video I see on my computer using EASYCAP video capture device. I also have a webcam. When I try running any OPENCV videocapture code in C++ it picks video only from my webcam and not the analog camera.

I can see the video from analog camera in Windows Movie maker but C++ wont access it. I noticed that the capture device is stored in the device manager as a sound,video and game controller while the webcam is stored as a imaging device. Is it not showing this feed because OPENCV wont recognize it.

Can anyone please advice me how they connect their analog camera (FPV, IR, etc) to the computer and process it. I have to process the video from a external analog camera which I connect to the PC using a video capture device.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `VideoCapture cap(1);`....the difference is using "1" instead of "0" in `cap()`

Comment: I did that. When I do that the PC shuts off. The video capture device identifies itself as a video controller rather than a imaging device. How can I solve that

Answer (score 0):

i struggled with the same problem (using python instead) and hope it helps!

[the original thread + answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146205/grab-frame-ntsctousb-dongle-opencv2-python-wrapper/22183737#22183737)